# Can the dietary fibres as chemical compounds be regarded as polymers?

Tags: biochemistry, diet, organic-chemistry, bioinorganic-chemistry

At the level of molecular structure, can the dietary fibres be regarded as polymers?

Comment: About which dietary fibers are you thinking?

Answer (score 3):

Dietary fibers are the indigestible portion of food derived from plants.

Most of these are indeed polymers of sugars (that is, a chain of repeated basic unit of carbohydrate), for example [cellulose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulose), [alginate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alginic_acid) or [pectin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pectin). They have glycosidic bonds that cannot be broken down by enzymes found in humans, and are thus indigestible.

But there are exceptions, for example [raffinose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raffinose), a trisaccharide found in beans & cabbage, is also categorised as a dietary fiber, as it is not breakable by human enzymes.